# pip, easy_install, curl, and manual install do not work for pyobjc - error code 1

Tags: python, pip, easy-install, pyobjc

I have tried doing everything I can think of and everything I've found on the internet but I still get this error. At the very bottom you can see the exact "error code 1" message I'm talking about. I'm on Yosemite and Python 2.7

Tried:
reinstalling setuptools -
completely uninstalling python which was a pain -
manually running the setup.py file -

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I've now spent about 20 hours on this and give up.

```
   Downloading pyobjc-core-3.0.4.tar.gz (2.2MB): 2.2MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/17/d7pv3h7x29l6tyk5zzc4wtrr0000gn/T/pip_build_ilya/pyobjc-core/setup.py) egg_info for package pyobjc-core

    warning: no directories found matching 'Scripts'
    warning: no directories found matching 'setup-lib'
    warning: no directories found matching 'source-deps'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.DS_Store' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dSYM/*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dSYM' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found anywhere in distribution
Downloading/unpacking pyobjc-framework-AddressBook==3.0.4 (from pyobjc)
  Downloading pyobjc-framework-AddressBook-3.0.4.tar.gz (51kB): 51kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/private/var/folders/17/d7pv3h7x29l6tyk5zzc4wtrr0000gn/T/pip_build_ilyakhruschev/pyobjc-framework-AddressBook/setup.py) egg_info for package pyobjc-framework-AddressBook
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-11.3-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py:2510: PEP440Warning: 'pyobjc (core-2.2)' is being parsed as a legacy, non PEP 440, version. You may find odd behavior and sort order. In particular it will be sorted as less than 0.0. It is recommend to migrate to PEP 440 compatible versions.
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-11.3-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py:2510: PEP440Warning: 'pyobjc (core-2.2b1)' is being parsed as a legacy, non PEP 440, version. You may find odd behavior and sort order. In particular it will be sorted as less than 0.0. It is recommend to migrate to PEP 440 compatible versions.
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-11.3-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py:2510: PEP440Warning: 'pyobjc (core-2.2b2)' is being parsed as a legacy, non PEP 440, version. You may find odd behavior and sort order. In particular it will be sorted as less than 0.0. It is recommend to migrate to PEP 440 compatible versions.
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-11.3-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py:2510: PEP440Warning: 'pyobjc (core-2.3)' is being parsed as a legacy, non PEP 440, version. You may find odd behavior and sort order. In particular it will be sorted as less than 0.0. It is recommend to migrate to PEP 440 compatible versions.
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-11.3-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py:2510: PEP440Warning: 'pyobjc (core-2.4)' is being parsed as a legacy, non PEP 440, version. You may find odd behavior and sort order. In particular it will be sorted as less than 0.0. It is recommend to migrate to PEP 440 compatible versions.
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-11.3-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py:2510: PEP440Warning: 'pyobjc (core-2.5.1)' is being parsed as a legacy, non PEP 440, version. You may find odd behavior and sort order. In particular it will be sorted as less than 0.0. It is recommend to migrate to PEP 440 compatible versions.
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-11.3-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py:2510: PEP440Warning: 'pyobjc (core-3.0.1)' is being parsed as a legacy, non PEP 440, version. You may find odd behavior and sort order. In particular it will be sorted as less than 0.0. It is recommend to migrate to PEP 440 compatible versions.
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-11.3-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py:2510: PEP440Warning: 'pyobjc (core-3.0.3)' is being parsed as a legacy, non PEP 440, version. You may find odd behavior and sort order. In particular it will be sorted as less than 0.0. It is recommend to migrate to PEP 440 compatible versions.
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-11.3-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py:2510: PEP440Warning: 'pyobjc (core-3.0.4)' is being parsed as a legacy, non PEP 440, version. You may find odd behavior and sort order. In particular it will be sorted as less than 0.0. It is recommend to migrate to PEP 440 compatible versions.
    warning: no directories found matching 'Scripts'
    warning: no directories found matching 'setup-lib'
    warning: no directories found matching 'source-deps'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.DS_Store' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dSYM/*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dSYM' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found anywhere in distribution
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/17/d7pv3h7x29l6tyk5zzc4wtrr0000gn/T/pip_build_ilyakhruschev/pyobjc-framework-AddressBook/setup.py", line 35, in <module>
        if fn.startswith('_AddressBook')
      File "pyobjc_setup.py", line 460, in setup
        **k
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 265, in __init__
      File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 311, in fetch_build_eggs
      File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 797, in resolve
      File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1047, in best_match
      File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1059, in obtain
      File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 378, in fetch_build_egg
      File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 619, in easy_install
      File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 649, in install_item
      File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 834, in install_eggs
      File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1055, in build_and_install
      File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1043, in run_setup
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: Cannot locate a working compiler
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-11.3-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py:2510: PEP440Warning: 'pyobjc (core-2.2)' is being parsed as a legacy, non PEP 440, version. You may find odd behavior and sort order. In particular it will be sorted as less than 0.0. It is recommend to migrate to PEP 440 compatible versions.

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-11.3-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py:2510: PEP440Warning: 'pyobjc (core-2.2b1)' is being parsed as a legacy, non PEP 440, version. You may find odd behavior and sort order. In particular it will be sorted as less than 0.0. It is recommend to migrate to PEP 440 compatible versions.

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-11.3-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py:2510: PEP440Warning: 'pyobjc (core-2.2b2)' is being parsed as a legacy, non PEP 440, version. You may find odd behavior and sort order. In particular it will be sorted as less than 0.0. It is recommend to migrate to PEP 440 compatible versions.

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-11.3-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py:2510: PEP440Warning: 'pyobjc (core-2.3)' is being parsed as a legacy, non PEP 440, version. You may find odd behavior and sort order. In particular it will be sorted as less than 0.0. It is recommend to migrate to PEP 440 compatible versions.

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-11.3-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py:2510: PEP440Warning: 'pyobjc (core-2.4)' is being parsed as a legacy, non PEP 440, version. You may find odd behavior and sort order. In particular it will be sorted as less than 0.0. It is recommend to migrate to PEP 440 compatible versions.

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-11.3-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py:2510: PEP440Warning: 'pyobjc (core-2.5.1)' is being parsed as a legacy, non PEP 440, version. You may find odd behavior and sort order. In particular it will be sorted as less than 0.0. It is recommend to migrate to PEP 440 compatible versions.

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-11.3-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py:2510: PEP440Warning: 'pyobjc (core-3.0.1)' is being parsed as a legacy, non PEP 440, version. You may find odd behavior and sort order. In particular it will be sorted as less than 0.0. It is recommend to migrate to PEP 440 compatible versions.

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-11.3-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py:2510: PEP440Warning: 'pyobjc (core-3.0.3)' is being parsed as a legacy, non PEP 440, version. You may find odd behavior and sort order. In particular it will be sorted as less than 0.0. It is recommend to migrate to PEP 440 compatible versions.

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-11.3-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py:2510: PEP440Warning: 'pyobjc (core-3.0.4)' is being parsed as a legacy, non PEP 440, version. You may find odd behavior and sort order. In particular it will be sorted as less than 0.0. It is recommend to migrate to PEP 440 compatible versions.

warning: no directories found matching 'Scripts'

warning: no directories found matching 'setup-lib'

warning: no directories found matching 'source-deps'

warning: no previously-included files matching '.DS_Store' found anywhere in distribution

warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution

warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution

warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution

warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dSYM/*' found anywhere in distribution

warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dSYM' found anywhere in distribution

warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found anywhere in distribution

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/private/var/folders/17/d7pv3h7x29l6tyk5zzc4wtrr0000gn/T/pip_build_ilyakhruschev/pyobjc-framework-AddressBook/setup.py", line 35, in <module>

    if fn.startswith('_AddressBook')

  File "pyobjc_setup.py", line 460, in setup

    **k

  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 111, in setup

    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 265, in __init__

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 311, in fetch_build_eggs

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 797, in resolve

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1047, in best_match

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1059, in obtain

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat/egg/setuptools/dist.py", line 378, in fetch_build_egg

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 619, in easy_install

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 649, in install_item

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 834, in install_eggs

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1055, in build_and_install

  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.5-fat/egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1043, in run_setup

distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: Cannot locate a working compiler

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/17/d7pv3h7x29l6tyk5zzc4wtrr0000gn/T/pip_build_ilyakhruschev/pyobjc-framework-AddressBook
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/ilyakhruschev/.pip/pip.lo
```

Comment: Do you have `xcode` installed?

Comment: yep, checked that too - installed and updated to 6.x

Comment: And `which cc` prints the path to your compiler?

Comment: EDIT: I figured out what this mean now. which cc prints to /usr/bin/cc but I dont know where my compiler is nor do i know where to find it